# How do I create a Grand Total Summary based on a Group Summarized Formula In Crystal 10?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have the following formula: @Sales_Cost

```
(Sum({Estimate_Retail_Inventory_Change___Detail.Sales_Ret_Final_Amount}, {Estimate_Retail_Inventory_Change___Detail.Inv ID}) -
(Sum ({Estimate_Retail_Inventory_Change___Detail.Sales_Ret_Final_Amount}, {Estimate_Retail_Inventory_Change___Detail.Inv ID}) * 
{@GM%_For_Cost_Sales}))
```

This produces the following results and I have placed in my GH2 section:

```
                         592.77
                         1038.26
                         2628.38
                         3598.62
                         356.58
```

I want to total those values for my Report Footer, but I get the error message, "This field cannot be summarized".

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a manual running total.  To do this you will create 3 new formula fields.

The first one goes in the report header to initialize the running total variable.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar manualTotal :=0;
```

The second one goes in the group header with your summary formula.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar manualTotal := manualTotal + {@Sales_Cost};
```

The third one goes in your report footer to display the calculated value.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
NumberVar manualTotal;
manualTotal;;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `{@GM%_For_Cost_Sales}` will not vary within each `Inv Id` value (though it could vary *across different* values) and that the group for GH2 is on `Inv Id`, the simplest way to do this would be to change your formula item to:

```
{Estimate_Retail_Inventory_Change___Detail.Sales_Ret_Final_Amount} * 
(1 - {@GM%_For_Cost_Sales})
```

- and place summed @Sales_Cost fields into both your GH2 group header and report footer sections.